# How to launch application after install in specific working directory + a bit extra

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using WIX to generate an MSI that our client uses to deploy an application on their network using an automated system.

Currently I'm having two issues:

1. Our application needs to be started after successful installation - I've found [the following article](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html) - but I can't find information on how to set the working directory to the directory where the application is installed.
2. Is there a way for me to detect if the application is running in the installer and

   1. If the MSI is run without a GUI simply shut it down (possibly requiring a certain flag/feature to be set on the commandline)
   2. If the MSI is run with a gui show the normal "the following application is running, yada yada - do you want to close it?" and then take the appropriate action.

PS. It was quite a few months ago I created this installer - and even then I basicly felt like I had no idea what I was doing. So assuming I have zero knowledge of this would help me alot, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ShellExecute custom action sets the current directory.

[How To: Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html)

If it doesn't, you could write a custom action to do so.  But I'd suggest fixing the client to not be sensitive to the current directory.

Comment: While your link is the exact same I linked to myself. I do agree that just changing the program to not be so sensitive to the current working directory it is started up in is a sensible solution, so I will accept.